# Right click with Voice Control

Tags: macos, accessibility, voice-control

Is it possible to add (or enable a built-in) Voice Control command to perform a **Right Click** in Mac OS X?

That is,  similar to the  built-in *`"Single Click"`* and *`"Double Click"`* voice commands.

Comment: What happens when you say "Mouse Right Click"?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using the latest version of macOS Big Sur.

On my system, all I need to do is speak the phrase “Control Click” and wherever my mouse cursor is at that moment, it performs a Right Click.  However, if I speak the phrase “Show Commands” and search through all of the mouse related commands, I do not see the “Control Click” command listed anywhere.

Comment: Amazing, but how did you detected that  trick? This  secret command  is not listed in the Accessibility pane in System Preferences  as well

Comment: By the way, it's working with Command Click as well. And then - I'm asking, where is the complete list? Maybe there are more tricks